# How to change a specific type's element name globally?

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

Let's say there is a class named

```java
// with respect.
public class BlaiseDoughan {
}
```

I know I can change the element's name like this.

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class MyRoot {

    @XmlElement(name = "blaise-doughan") // I want this
    private BlaiseDoughan blaiseDoughan
}
```

Is there any way to permanently set the target element name of `BlaiseDoughan` to `blaise-doughan` in every or any occurrence without `name` attribute?

I mean

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class SomeOtherRoot {

    @XmlElement // without the [name = "blaise-doughan"] part?
    private BlaiseDoughan blaiseDoughan
}
```

Is there any `package-level` technique for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

### Java Model

**BlaiseDoughan**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="blaise-doughan")
public class BlaiseDoughan {

}
```

**MyRoot**

And then every reference to it could be mapped with `@XmlElementRef`.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyRoot {

    @XmlElementRef
    private BlaiseDoughan blaiseDoughan;

    public void setBlaiseDoughan(BlaiseDoughan blaiseDoughan) {
        this.blaiseDoughan = blaiseDoughan;
    }

}
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyRoot.class);

        MyRoot myRoot = new MyRoot();
        myRoot.setBlaiseDoughan(new BlaiseDoughan());

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(myRoot, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myRoot>
    <blaise-doughan/>
</myRoot>
```

### Why This Works

`@XmlElementRef` corresponds to using `ref` in the element definition:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xsd:complexType name="blaiseDoughan"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="myRoot">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element ref="blaise-doughan"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="myRoot" type="myRoot"/>
   <xsd:element name="blaise-doughan" type="blaiseDoughan"/>
</xsd:schema>
```